# POSTGRES COPY FROM PROGRAM into a dynamic table with unknown columns

Tags: postgresql

I am looking to copy from a .csv file which can be anything with any no. of columns. I need to insert these into a table that is created dynamically based on the number of columns in the file. The csv is located at a url say for example https://data.sfgov.org/api/views/yitu-d5am/rows.csv.

How do I use postgres COPY FROM COMMAND for achieving this? Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot do that, since `COPY` does not create the table for you. Write a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not know the number/types of rows upfront then I would suggest that you do like this:

- (1) import your CSV into a (temporary?) table with a single text column without splitting. Use `backspace` character as a delimiter so that the whole imported line will remain intact;

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rawtext_t (rawtext text);
COPY rawtext_t FROM <file_name> WITH (format 'csv', delimiter E'\b');
```

- (2) run a query that [splits the CSV into a text array](https://gist.github.com/carymrobbins/b8e7340ce63a22e8d33c) - function `parse_csv`, and then use the resulting set of text arrays as relevant (maybe map/insert into the 'real' target table)

```sql
WITH rawdata AS
(
 SELECT parse_csv(rawtext) arr FROM rawtext_t
) 
INSERT INTO real_t (...fields...) 
SELECT arr[1], arr[3], ...
FROM rawdata;

TRUNCATE TABLE rawtext_t;
```

You can add a `WHERE` clause in the second `SELECT` statement in order to filter incoming rows if necessary.

**Another option** - a very good one in my understanding - is to use the excellent [file_textarray_fdw](https://github.com/adunstan/file_text_array_fdw) to more or less the same effect.

Hope that this gives you ideas & helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for the delay in getting back. I shall try out this solution!